# ElasticSearch edge-ngram not working

Tags: java, sql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I have configured the my index with the following settings and the matchAll query results the have a value "trial" in the field IPRANGE.

The settings:

```
{
        "settings" : {
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "autocomplete_filter": { 
                        "type":     "edge_ngram",
                        "min_gram": 1,
                        "max_gram": 5
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "autocomplete": {
                        "type":      "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "autocomplete_filter" 
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
            "mappings" : {
               "users" : {
                   "properties" : {
                       "IPRANGE" : {
                           "type" : "string",
                           "analyzer" : "autocomplete"
                       }
                   }
               }
            },
               refresh_interval: "1000"
    }
```

But when I search with following payload it doesn't return results, ie is 0 hits.

URL:

```
http://xxxxxx:9200/db2/users/_search
```

Payload:

```
{

  "query": {

  "match": {

     "IPRANGE": "tr"

  }

  }

}
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How have you indexed the document? Here is an example that works:

I changed the mapping so that the `autocomplete` analyzer is used to index the `IPRANGE` field, when searching against the field the default analyzer will be used (you don't want to split the search term in same way).

```
/POST http://localhost:9200/test
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "autocomplete_filter": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 5
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "autocomplete_filter"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "users": {
            "properties": {
                "IPRANGE": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "search_analyzer": "autocomplete"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Index the document

```
/POST http://localhost:9200/test/users/1/
{
   "IPRANGE":"trial"
}
```

Search request:

```
/POST http://localhost:9200/test/users/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "IPRANGE": "tr"
    }
  }
}
```

Returns the following result:

```
{
    took: 10
    timed_out: false
    _shards: {
        total: 5
        successful: 5
         failed: 0
    }
    hits: {
        total: 1
        max_score: 0.30685282
        hits: [
            {
                _index: test
                _type: users
                _id: 1
                _score: 0.30685282
                _source: {
                    IPRANGE: trial
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to restart the elasticsearch server for the setting to apply? In addition is there any api to reindex rather than restart?

Comment: You can use the `_mapping PUT` API to change the `users` mapping, it will merge the old mapping with the new mapping: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html. Then you would need to re-index the documents. If you have a large amount of documents have a look at the re-index plugin: https://github.com/karussell/elasticsearch-reindex